# MS Access VBA empty TextBox

Tags: vba

I am handling a Form with several unbounded TextBoxes.

While such a TextBox has the Focus I would like to check if the user has made a reasonable Input.

For this I check the TextBox.Text method against several criteria.

This works fine unless the user has not made any Input in this TextBox.

In this case the TextBox.Text method has no value (not even NULL) and the Programm produces Runtime-Error 2196.

Does anybody have an idea how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

ChessmasterIII

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code it'll be hard to tell but you could check the value for Null or an empty String

```
If IsNull(CONTROL) or CONTROL="" Then
    ' Do some stuff
End if
```

[599CD Article](https://599cd.com/tips/access/null-zls/)

**Edit**

Try just the control name and not with .Text or just CONTROL.SetFocus before checking the .Text property

Comment: This is the issue.

As soon as I adress the Contro.Text-method in any way (checking for IsNull, checking for "") the program responds with runtime error 2196.

In the meantime I have found out that this seems to be special behaviour of TextBoxes with Password-Format.

Other TextBoxes do have the NullString ("") as the value of TextBox.Text in the KeyDown-Event.

Comment: Try a Me.Dirty = False, that'll commit any bound values to the data source then you can do your checks

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use

```
If Me.textbox <> vbNullString Then
     'do stuff
Else
     'don't do stuff
End if
```